# Can a USB-C port be used for video (maybe audio too), data and power transfer simultaneously?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, external-hard-drive, displayport, usb-c

Because of my work, I'm planning to buy a 4K monitor, and since I hate cables I would like to connect it to my laptop ([ASUS Zenbook UX501VW](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-Pro-UX501VW/specifications/)) with the smallest number of cables possible. As far as I know, the USB-C port in my laptop supports DisplayPort and Thunderbolt protocol, and also capable of power delivery.

One of the candidate monitors is the [LG 27UK850-W](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27UK850-W-4k-uhd-led-monitor). The specs say that its USB-C port is also DisplayPort, data and power transfer capable, at the same time, but as far as I know (I'm pretty confused with all these new USB protocols), different protocols need different cables. I mean I've read that a DP capable cable might not work as a PD or a data transfer cable.

So tl;dr: Can I use only one cable to connect my Zenbook to an external monitor, an external HDD (through the monitor's regular USB ports), and charge it in the same time if I pick the right monitor?

Comment: “TL;DR” is supposed to be followed by a summary; but you never mentioned the external disk until then.

Comment: I always included 'data transfer'. I thought that it was evident that I want to use a external drives too.

Comment: Well, I was on the verge of criticizing “video, audio and data” as redundant, since audio/video *are* data.   No, your statement “I would like to connect it (the 4K monitor) to my laptop with the smallest number of cables possible” does *not* make it clear that you also want to connect the monitor to some other device (or vice-versa).

Comment: OK. Then good sir, please accept my deepest apologies for my cruel mistake.

Comment: No need to be snarky; just try to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has more to do with the devices than the cables.  It's no different from when you plug in, say, a Samsung Galaxy phone into a computer, and it charges while you transfer files around with it.  What will make the difference is the power output from the television; if the port is powered enough, it may be able to charge any device which accepts power from it while in use.  If not, you'll likely see the battery deplete slightly more slowly, but it will still deplete.  Note that most TVs do not output a lot of power from their USB hubs, even on C spec.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I check the minimum power my laptop can be charged with.